# Java variable assignment to a double. Why is the value converted to a double?

Tags: java

```
int i, j, k;
double a, b, c;
```

The following sequence of statements is correct:

```
i = 3;
a = i + 5;
b = 12 / a;
c = i + b;
c = c - b;
j = 12 / 3;
a = 12 / 3;
b = 13 / 3;
// a gets the value 8.0
// b gets the value 1.5
// c gets the value 4.5
// c now gets the value 3.0
// j gets the value 4;
// a gets the value 4.0
// b gets the value 4.0!
```

In the last line, why does b get the value 4.0? 13 / 3 in Java is 4 isn't it? Why does the 4 get converted to a double? Is that what the variable type does to the value? I thought doubles can hold integers?

Comment: because you said b was a double at the top....

Comment: So the type casted variable will convert the value (even if it's an int) to its own type?

Comment: Yes. A double variable always refers to a double value. That's its type. That's true for all the other types (except that reference type can refer to nothing, i.e. be `null`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is called [assignment conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

> Assignment conversion occurs when the value of an expression is
>   assigned to a variable: the type of the expression must be
>   converted to the type of the variable.
>
> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion
> - a widening primitive conversion
> - a widening reference conversion
> - a boxing conversion optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

In this case, your assignment requires converting the value of the expression into `double` because that's the type of the target of the assignment. The conversion required is [widening primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), which changes the value of the expression into a type that has a wider range that includes that value.

In converting from `int` to `double`, you don't lose precision (a `double` can hold all the values of type `int` including all their digits, which a `float` can't). But that doesn't mean that the value is still an `int`. It has been converted to the `double` that represents the same value.

A variable of type `X` can never hold a value of any type other than `X` (except polymorphically, but that doesn't apply to primitive types like `int` and `double`).

Answer (score 0):

it works like this

b = 13 / 3   =>  b = int / int . So it takes 13/3 int and then it converts it to double.

if you want the correct you should do it like b = (double)13/(double)3;

Answer (score 0):

Since in `13/3` both values are integers the calculation is done in integer arithmetic and yields the (integer) value 4. Since b can only hold double values, it is assigned the (double) value 4, which depending on your method to display the value will be shown as 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The precision is already gone by the time you assign it.

You need to cast to double

```
b = ((double)13)/3
```

Comment: Please use proper English when answering on StackOverflow: "You", not "U". Also, format code properly. The answers are here to serve the community, it's not a chat application.

Answer (score 0):

if you write:

```
b = (double)13 / 3;
```

or

```
b = 13. / 3;
```

it won't do that. I think you know now why.